# Showing progress while waiting for all Tasks in List<Task> to complete

Tags: c#, .net, asynchronous, async-await, task

I'm currently trying to continuously print dots at the end of a line as a form of indeterminate progress, while a large list of Tasks are running, with this code:

```
start = DateTime.Now;
Console.Write("*Processing variables");
Task entireTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
Task progress = new Task(() => { while (!entireTask.IsCompleted) { Console.Write("."); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); } });
progress.Start();
entireTask.Wait();
timeDiff = DateTime.Now - start;
Console.WriteLine("\n*Operation completed in {0} seconds.", timeDiff.TotalSeconds);
```

Where `tasks` is from `List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>();`, 
and `tasks.Add(Task.Run(() => someMethodAsync()));` has occurred 10000's of times. 
This code currently works, however, is this the correct way of accomplishing this, and is this the most cost-effective way?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

There are certainly several ways this can be solved and one of them is yours. However it is not really a good practice to start long running tasks especially when they do nothing than synchronous waiting (that is Thread.Sleep).

You should consider refactoring your code in a technical and a domain part. The technical part is:

1. Wait until all Tasks in a given collection have completed
2. If that takes longer do regular progress reports

The following code might help to understand this a bit better. It starts four tasks which simulate different async operations and waits for all of them to complete. If this takes longer than 250ms the call of WhenAllEx keeps on calling a lambda for reoccuring progress report.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var tasks = Enumerable.Range(0, 4).Select(taskNumber => Task.Run(async () =>
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Task {0} starting", taskNumber);
        await Task.Delay((taskNumber + 1) * 1000);
        Console.WriteLine("Task {0} stopping", taskNumber);
    })).ToList();

    // Wait for all tasks to complete and do progress report
    var whenAll = WhenAllEx(
        tasks, 
        _ => Console.WriteLine("Still in progress. ({0}/{1} completed)", _.Count(task => task.IsCompleted), tasks.Count()));

    // Usually never wait for asynchronous operations unless your in Main
    whenAll.Wait();
    Console.WriteLine("All tasks finished");
    Console.ReadKey();
}

/// <summary>
/// Takes a collection of tasks and completes the returned task when all tasks have completed. If completion
/// takes a while a progress lambda is called where all tasks can be observed for their status.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="tasks"></param>
/// <param name="reportProgressAction"></param>
/// <returns></returns>
public static async Task WhenAllEx(ICollection<Task> tasks, Action<ICollection<Task>> reportProgressAction)
{
    // get Task which completes when all 'tasks' have completed
    var whenAllTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
    for (; ; )
    {
        // get Task which completes after 250ms
        var timer = Task.Delay(250); // you might want to make this configurable
        // Wait until either all tasks have completed OR 250ms passed
        await Task.WhenAny(whenAllTask, timer);
        // if all tasks have completed, complete the returned task
        if (whenAllTask.IsCompleted)
        {
            return;
        }
        // Otherwise call progress report lambda and do another round
        reportProgressAction(tasks);
    }
}
```

Comment: Will this line "var whenAllTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);" be blocked until all the tasks completes? and the code will always wait for all the tasks to complete and after that will run Task.Delay ?

Comment: Task.WhenAll(...) does not block but returns a task which completes when all tasks in the parameters have completed. The same for Task.Delay. It returns a task which completes after 250ms (in the example code). The trick is to wait for a third task which completes when either Task.WhenAll OR Task.Delay have completed. I'll add some comments to the code.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your detailed answer! I have two syntax questions. What is happening syntax-wise at the underscore you used in the parameters for `var whenAll`, and what is happening in the syntax of `for (; ; )`?

Comment: Oh sorry, the underscore is just the parameter name for the lambda expression. You might replace the underscore everywhere with for example "progressData" to make it cleaner! "for (;;)" is nothing else than an endless loop you have to "break out" by calling return or break.

Answer (score 15):

As Thomas mentioned, there are certainly several ways to handle this. The one that springs immediately to mind for me is:

```
start = DateTime.Now;
Console.Write("*Processing variables");
Task entireTask = Task.WhenAll(tasks);
while (await Task.WhenAny(entireTask, Task.Delay(1000)) != entireTask)
{
  Console.Write(".");
}
timeDiff = DateTime.Now - start;
Console.WriteLine("\n*Operation completed in {0} seconds.", timeDiff.TotalSeconds);
```

Note that this approach does use `await`, thus requiring this method to be `async`. Usually for console apps, I recommend having a `Main` just call `MainAsync`, so your blocking (or main loop) is all in one line of code and not mixed with any logic.

Comment: Is it possible to implement it that way, that we can report the real progress in percentage of the whole task execution? Any approach for that?
Unfortunately you cannot set a parameter like `List<Task`<SomeType>> to `WhenAny`... and here we only have one big task `entireTask`we have to wait for and check its completed state..

Comment: @Legends: Progress reports can be individual (as you currently have it), or they can be cumulative (move `current` into `DoProgress`). The individual progress reports are essentially saying "another one is done". The cumulative reports would say "these many have been done".

Answer (score 3):

Thomas' answer is good, you should accept it. I'll offer a version with a smaller code delta:

Replace this:

```
Task progress = new Task(() => { while (!entireTask.IsCompleted) { Console.Write("."); System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000); } });
progress.Start();
```

With this:

```
Task progressTask = Task.Run(async () => {
 while (!entireTask.IsCompleted) {
     Console.Write(".");
     await Task.Delay(1000);
 }
});
```

This is more efficient and, I think, cleaner code.

Thomas' version had the added benefit of terminating the progress task immediately once the "entireTask" has completed.

Comment: What is the benefit or difference in using `await Task.Delay(1000)` vs `System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(1000)`?

Comment: Also, syntax-wise, what is the meaning of `async` in the parameter for `Task.Run`?

Comment: Doesn't block. This saves a thread that otherwise would be busy waiting all the time.